# Can't sendSubviewToBack with MKMapView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

In Xcode I have created a `UITableView` with `Dynamic Prototypes`. The first cell is composed of a `button`, a `label`, and an `MKMapView`.

In my `...cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I use the following code:

```
UITableViewCell *header = [self getNewCell:@"entity_header"];

// Send map to back (put map behind everything else)
MKMapView *MapView = (MKMapView*)[header viewWithTag:2];
[tableView sendSubviewToBack:MapView];
// Also tried using `header` here. [header sendSubviewToBack:MapView];

// Set the image of the back button.
UIButton *backButton = (UIButton*)[header viewWithTag:1];
UIImage *backBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/backBtn.png"];
[backButton setImage:backBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tableView bringSubviewToFront:backButton];
// Also tried using `header` here. [header bringSubviewToFront:backButton];
```

**I would like to send the `MKMapView` behind the other components however the code above does not work as intended.**

NOTE: The reason I use `viewWithTag` here is so that I don't have to create outlets for all of the components. (It's tricky creating outlets from inside a `UITableViewCell` without using more implementation files)

Comment: [cell bringSubviewToFront:backButton]; use `cell` instead of `tableView` you component has been added on Cell not tableview..

Comment: Tried the above suggestion and it did not work. MKMapView is still on top of all other components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're using custom cell. So problem may be in this line. `MKMapView *MapView = (MKMapView*)[header viewWithTag:2];` Instead try this.

```
MKMapView *MapView = (MKMapView*)[header.contentView viewWithTag:2];
```

And they go with this .

```
[header.contentView sendSubviewToBack:MapView];
```

**Note:** If all content's subview have bounds less than `MKMapView` means, `MKMapView` always will be in screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the answer. =)